# how to disable scroll being shown after onhover of button?

Tags: php, scroll, yii2, adminlte

I am using yii2 , in that the scroll is normal if onhover of button in not caught. But when I try to click the button the scroll appears even if it is not required. I want to disable the scroll which happens unnecessarily. 
kindly help me. Please find the screen shots. [image: before hover of button]

[image: after hover of button]

Comment: So what are you actually doing on mouse over? Do you have any event in JS or in CSS defined? You need to show us all the relevant code.

Comment: I have used adminlte package, i have not captured any event @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Something is capturing an event that does something on mouse over. Do some debugging and find out what.